# Displaying images Django models

Tags: python, django

I am building my first website after finishing the [how to tango with django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com) tutorial and i am trying to add some images using the template language, but instead i get only little blue question mark icons

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Galery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Image(models.Model):
    galery = models.ForeignKey(Galery)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    materials = models.CharField(max_length = 150)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

galery.html

```
{%extends 'home/base.html'%}
{%load static%}
{%block body%}
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">My Projects</h1>
</div>
{%if image%}    
    {%for n in image%}  
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'media/{{n.image.url}}' %}">
            </a>
        </div>
    {%endfor%}
{%endif%}

{%endblock%}
```

settings.py (part)

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'media')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

EDIT: forgot to mention that i uploaded some images from the admin

EDIT2: in my urls.py i have

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.views.static',
    (r'media/(?P<path>.*)',
    'serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

Answer (score 0):

Django by default does not serve user-uploaded images. Set it up by adding the following URL conf:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is only for development. In production you will need to serve your files in a more scalable way (either directly from the HTTP server or even better, from a file storage service such as S3, or a CDN.)

For more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: I added this part to the projects urls.py butthen i get an error 'TypeError: url() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)'